# How to hide a part of the container widget beyond the screen without violating Flutter's layout constraints

Tags: flutter, user-interface, flutter-container

I am new to flutter. And i am trying to hide the bottom red part (see the first screenshot) of the blue container under the screen, in order to hide the buttom part of a white border and use this container for the animation. But it generates a problem (see see the second screenshot). Please help)

First screenshot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bMVz.png)

Second screenshot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3wDu.png)

This is the code of this Stack with two containers. I used the second one just for demonstration purposes. I need only one container.

```dart
...
 Stack(
              children: [
                
                Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  color: Colors.blue, 
                  height: 300, 
                ),
                Positioned(
                  bottom: 0,
                  left: 0,
                  right: 0,
                  child: ClipRect(
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                      heightFactor:
                          1, 
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.red,
                          border: Border.all(
                              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255)),
                        ),
                        height:
                            150,

                        
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                            'Bottom Hidden Container',
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),

...
```

I have tried to remove this problem, but nothing seems to work.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyQrW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `OverflowBox` widget allows its child to overflow its bounds without causing layout errors. Here's code:

```
 Stack(
  children: [
    Container(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      color: Colors.blue,
      height: 300,
    ),
    Positioned(
      bottom: 0,
      left: 0,
      right: 0,
      child: OverflowBox(
        maxHeight: 300, // Set the maximum height to control how much is shown
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.red,
            border: Border.all(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255)),
          ),
          height: 150,
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              'Bottom Hidden Container',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to make your page scrollable (`ListView` or `SingleChildScrollView` widget) so it doesn't overflow.

You can then use the `Opacity` widget to dynamically change its visibility.

You may also use a boolean value to make it appear conditionally. For example:

```
bool showContainer = false;
child: showContainer 
            ? Center(...)          //if true
            : SizedBox.shrink();   //if false
```

`SizedBox.shrink()` widget returns an empty box

Comment: But then it will be scrollable. I need it to overflow but without cousing an error.

Comment: You still have to use the scrollable widgets to avoid overflow error. You can use this parameter to stop it from scrolling: physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()

Comment: Or you can use the Expanded widget but this will resize your widgets

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken your trying to make a widget hidable, so just define a bool var like this:

```
bool isVisible = true;
```

after that, your widgets would be something like this:

```
Column(
            children: [
              InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  isVisible = !isVisible;
                  setState(() {});
                },
                child: Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  child: const Center(
                    child: Text('Blue Container'),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              if (isVisible)
                Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  color: Colors.red,
                  child: const Center(
                    child: Text('Red Container'),
                  ),
                ),
            ],
          ),
```

in this example by clicking the first container, the second container will be invisible. consider that your screen or your parent widget should be stateful.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did it already with `OverflowBox`